# Should the input options be included with the results in a job/task queue?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, jobs, job-scheduling, task-queue

I'm working on developing a job queue type system where Jobs can be added to a central queue. Processor then read jobs of the queue, run them, and store the results somewhere.

Each Job contains a list of tasks to perform in order and the options to use when running the Job and Tasks.

```
public class Job
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    IDictionary<string, string> Options { get; set; }
    public IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    IDictionary<string, string> Options { get; set; }
}
```

The processors will return results for the Jobs and associated Tasks which identify if the Job and Tasks succeeded and include a message describing the results.

```
public class JobResult
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    IList<TaskResult> TaskResults { get; set; }
}

public class TaskResult
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Yet if I were to create some kind of GUI or report showing the results of a Job I'd also want to show the details and options of the Job itself and not just the results alone. One way I've though to do this it to just add a reference to the `Job` to the `JobResult` class.

```
public class JobResult
{
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    IList<TaskResult> TaskResults { get; set; }

    public Job Job {get; set;} <-- Add Job details to JobResult
}
```

Yet with this there isn't a direct association between the Task and TaskResult other then their position in the respective lists.

Alternatively, JobResult and Task could simply inherit from Job and Task respectively adding result status properties.

```
public class JobResult: Job
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
}

public class TaskResult: Task
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
}
```

How do systems like this typically work? It it a bad idea/code smell to be returning a copy of the input with the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote for associating `JobResult` with `Job`, because a `Job` isn't a `JobResult` and vice versa.

A `JobResult` **has an associated `Job`**, and in object-oriented programming world, a *has a* relationship means [*composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Comment: Ah yeah good point. It's definitely a "has a" relationship. What do you think of my update above regarding of omitting the separate results classes and combining the results into the Job and Task classes?

Comment: @EricAnastas Honestly I would remove your new content and I would add a new question. You can't expand a question overtime and transform a Q&A into a real-time chat............

Comment: @EricAnastas You asked some something very concrete and I answered it. If it was useful for you, you should mark my answer as the accepted one, and copy-paste the other question as part of a new question body